# heroku run bash does not execute .exe letsencrypt-win-simple

Tags: python, bash, heroku, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install letsencrypt for my heroku app.

So far I found out that letsencrypt does not work for windows. Initially I wanted to create the certificates localy and upload them to heroku. Heroku offers a simple upload mechanic if you have the necessary .pem files.

I found [letsencrypt-win-simple](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple/wiki/How-to-Run).

I downloaded the ZIP and tried to run it localy, it worked. But it needs access to the server, so I uploaded the whole folder to my heroku git repository and tried to run the `letsencrypt.exe` directly with `heroku bash`:

[image]

It does not execute the .exe.

**EDIT**

I tried `./letsencrypt.exe`

```
~/letsencrypt-win-simple $ ./letsencrypt.exe
bash: ./letsencrypt.exe: Permission denied
```

Comment: as default `bash` doesn't run command in current folder - it runs only commands from folders in `PATH` variable - But you can try to run with full path or shorter `./letsencrypt.exe`

Comment: Worked now, but caused: bash: ´./letsencrypt.exe: Permission denied´

Comment: you may try with `root` permissions using `sudo ./letsencrypt.exe`

Comment: Gives me: bash: sudo: command not found. I use a python buildpack, could this be an issue?

Comment: Maybe you have to change file privilages before you run. ie. `chmod a+x letsencrypt.exe` - so now it will be "eXecutable" for "All"

Comment: Works now, but getting this: bash: ./letsencrypt.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: `.exe` means program for Windows or DOS and as I know Heroku mostly uses Linux. Are you using Windows Server ?

Comment: Yes I am using windows server

Comment: `Exec format error` may means broken file - maybe you have to upload it again. Or maybe you have version for different processor.